# How to prevent trigger ngModelChange event for first time?

Tags: javascript, angular, events

Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators, FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({

  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div id="my-div">
    <h1>Ng2 DateTime Picker French Test</h1>

    <input [(ngModel)]="myDate" 
      (change)="myChange($event)"
      (ngModelChange)="myNgModelChange($event)"
      ng2-datetime-picker
      date-only="true"/>
</div>

  `,
  styles: [`
    div { font-family: Courier; font-size: 13px}
    input { min-width: 200px; font-size: 15px; }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {

  myDate: any = "2016-12-28";

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    moment.locale('fr-ca');
  }

  myChange(ev) {
    alert("input field is manually changed to", ev.target.value)
  }

  myNgModelChange(value) {
    alert("ngModel is changed to " + value);
  }
}
```

When I load the page, it auto trigger ngModelChange event. But if i don't set myDate value, then it will not trigger event. So how to prevent ngModelChange for first time? and here is [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/D7CU5p70YW578BaaO5B8?p=preview&open=app.component.ts)

Comment: Doesn't make sense, you're changing it but you want it not to change ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @Milad i just initialize the value, i think it not to change ,i init myDate value,then it trigger ngModelChange event

Comment: what should I expect to see in ? it doesn't alert for the first time, I don't know what's the issue

Comment: here is :https://plnkr.co/edit/D7CU5p70YW578BaaO5B8?p=preview&open=app.component.ts

Comment: preventing ngModelChange event trigger would be bit difficult, instead you can use a boolean to stop the method call

Answer (score 4):

## [Plunker (2)](https://plnkr.co/edit/LHJQPeYML3uypdmqry2M?open=app.component.ts&p=preview)

**Update (2)**: Extend current setup to allow for multiple dates.

## 1. Put everything in an array

```
myDates = [
  {
    id: 1, // You can have an undefined value
    value: undefined,
  },
  {
    id: 2, // You can set an initial date
    value: new Date("Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)"),
  },
  {
    id: 3 // You can also leave out the value
  }
];
```

## 2. Prepare the array on component creation

```
setup() {
  this.myDates.forEach((dateObj, i) => {
    this.myDates[i].ignored = false;
    this.myDates[i].initValue = dateObj.value;
  });
}
```

## 3. Loop through array in template

```
<div *ngFor="let myDate of myDates; let i = index">
  <input
    [ngModel]="myDate.value"
    (ngModelChange)="myNgModelChange($event, i)"
    ng2-datetime-picker
    date-format="DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm"
    hour="23"
    minute='59'
    date-only="true"/>
</div>
```

## Full Component (2)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div id="my-div">
    <h1>Ng2 DateTime Picker French Test</h1>

    <div *ngFor="let myDate of myDates; let i = index">
      <input
        [ngModel]="myDate.value"
        (ngModelChange)="myNgModelChange($event, i)"
        ng2-datetime-picker
        date-format="DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm"
        hour="23"
        minute='59'
        date-only="true"/>
    </div>

</div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    div { font-family: Courier; font-size: 13px}
    input { min-width: 200px; font-size: 15px; }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
  myDates = [
    {
      id: 1, // You can have an undefined value
      value: undefined,
    },
    {
      id: 2, // You can set an initial date
      value: new Date("Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)"),
    },
    {
      id: 3 // You can also leave out the value
    }
  ];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    moment.locale('fr-ca');
    this.setup();
  }

  setup() {
    this.myDates.forEach((dateObj, i) => {
      this.myDates[i].ignored = false;
      this.myDates[i].initValue = dateObj.value;
    });
  }

  myChange(ev) {
    alert("input field is manually changed to", ev.target.value)
  }


  myNgModelChange(value, index) {
    if (this.myDates[index].ignored || this.myDates[index].initValue === undefined) {
      alert("ngModel is changed to " + value);
    }
    this.myDates[index].ignored = true;
  }
}
```

## [Plunker (1)](https://plnkr.co/edit/guGnJgWzUWycaOgBXUKG?open=app.component.ts&p=preview)

**Original with update (1)**: allows for an `undefined` initial date value.

### 1. Set the initial value

When the component loads store it's initial value like this:

```
this.initValue = this.myDate;
```

### 2. Ignore the first event by using a variable unless the initial value was undefined like this:

```
myNgModelChange(value) {
  if (this.ignoredFirstEvent || this.initValue === undefined) {
    alert("ngModel is changed to " + value);
  }
  this.ignoredFirstEvent = true;
}
```

## Full Component (1)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div id="my-div">
    <h1>Ng2 DateTime Picker French Test</h1>

    <input [ngModel]="myDate"
      (ngModelChange)="myNgModelChange($event)"
      ng2-datetime-picker
      date-format="DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm"
      hour="23"
      minute='59'
      date-only="true"/>
</div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    div { font-family: Courier; font-size: 13px}
    input { min-width: 200px; font-size: 15px; }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
  ignoredFirstEvent = false;
  initValue;
  myDate:any;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    moment.locale('fr-ca');
    this.initValue = this.myDate;
  }

  myChange(ev) {
    alert("input field is manually changed to", ev.target.value)
  }


  myNgModelChange(value) {
    if (this.ignoredFirstEvent || this.initValue === undefined) {
      alert("ngModel is changed to " + value);
    }
    this.ignoredFirstEvent = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, it could run well, but for other condition, if i have no value ,then i input value for first time. so, ngModelChange will not be triggered.

Comment: You're right, I just updated it to account for an undefined initial value. Thanks!

Comment: oh, i think another condition. if i have three or more same input element, then if you still set flag ,it still hard to work!!

Comment: I just extended it to allow for multiple dates